# What is the best way to load a .sys file in C#?

Tags: c#, driver

I have tried DllImport, But it seems more complicated than it needs to be. I was wondering if Assembly.Load would be easier?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I tried to open this page, the internet crashed. That is a sure sign that you should stop right now!

Comment: "What are you trying to achieve?"

We have a driver which retreives data from our hardware. I am trying to make a WPF front end which displays that data.

Comment: I'm an intern, I've never used drivers before

Comment: How did you do it using DllImport? I have the same problem but can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Wow. This was a long time ago... I barely understood what I was doing then. Looking back at the code I have managed to find, I loaded up [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) (which it depends upon) from Kernel32.dll which allowed me to access the Driver.

Sorry this reply is late. Not checked the site for a while.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.sys files are windows driver files and you cannot load them in a process neither in a unmanaged process nor in a managed process. sys files are loaded in kernel by registering them with service control manager. So basically you cannot load a sys file using C#, although you can start a service using C# and this service is a driver type service.

Comment: I want to retreive data from hardware using a driver. Can I do this with a service?

Comment: Yes, register that driver, load that driver, and then using the API of the driver (which may be ReadFile or IOCTL based) you can do that

Comment: Can I register the driver programmatically?